# How to store an inclusion/exclusion list in Mongo without storing every single item to represent a selection of "All"

Tags: arrays, mongodb, data-modeling

My app has geofencing functionality. In the UI there is a table which lets the user add a country to either the "blocked" or the "allowed" list. The overwhelming majority of objects in the collection do not need geofencing and thus by default all countries should be in the allowed list for a new object.

How do I represent the 3 possible states (all, some, none) in Mongo? The last two are obvious - an array containing either some 2 letter country codes, or none. But what about the first case? I feel like it would be a massive waste of bytes to store however many (200+) country codes for each object.

The two alternatives I can come up with are:

Using a value of `object.allowed_countries = [ 1 ]` which also doesn't scream right to me.

Or storing an additional property to represent the global "all".

```
object: {
   geofencing: {
      enabled: true | false,
      blocked_countries: [ ]
   }
}
```

Is there anything smarter I'm not thinking of?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: perhaps a `default` value in the fencing object to indicate whether an unlisted country should be included or excluded